Where is the auto changing workspace setting?
When I change the Workspace tab to "Modeling", the object mode switches to Edit mode. When I change the workspace tab to "Sculpt", the object mode switches to Sculpt mode.
I would like to make the "weight paint" mode of that.

You will find the solution here: Changing Workspace Without Going Into Edit Mode if you just want to know how you make the automatic mode switch. Or do you need assistance for creating a custom workspace in general?
